# How do I verify that $\sin (\theta)$ and $\cos (\theta)$ are functions?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, trigonometry

I am studying pre-calculus mathematics at the moment, and I need help in verifying if  $\sin (\theta)$ and $\cos (\theta)$ are functions? I want to demonstrate that for any angle $\theta$ that there is only one associated value of $\sin (\theta)$ and $\cos (\theta)$. How do I go about showing this?

Comment: What is you definition of $\sin\theta$ and $\cos\theta$ ?

Comment: @lhf : You have changed your comment.. this makes more sense than previous one... :D

Comment: @lhf, how many definitions are there? Could you list them, so I can tell you which I think is closest to what I have in my mind. Thanks.

Comment: There is the power series, the differential equation, the functional equation with continuity condition and derivative at 0,...

Comment: @LutzL, which one do you think would be the one I'm most likely to come across in Precalculus maths?

Comment: @Assad, the point is not about *how many definitions*, usually all the definitions implies the same properties. So if you could tell what definition you are following, we could try proving that your fact follows from the definition.

Comment: @boywholived, I am currently studying the Unit Circle, and am trying to describe position of a point P(x,y) on this circle. The textbook asked for me to verify the "rules used to match an angle with its cosine and sine do, in fact, satisfy the definition of a function".

Comment: You're probably working with the definition using the unit circle. The property of being a function comes from the fact that angle itself is meaningful, and that any given angle picks out a unique point on the unit circle. The unit circle is what $S^1$, in Christian Blatter's answer, refers to.

Comment: As he mentions, it's difficult to make this precise, and therefore difficult for us to really "prove", at the level that you're currently at, that it's a function. One way to make it precise, for instance, is that $(\cos \theta, \sin \theta)$ parametrizes the unit circle by arc-length, starting at $(1, 0)$ when $\theta=0$ and traversing counter-clockwise. But you need calculus to make sense of "parametrizing by arc-length"...

Answer (score 3):

Usually one begins studying the $\sin$ function in connection with right triangles. Here the notion of angle is not questioned, so I shall stick with this intuitive concept. It follows that we have $\sin \theta$ defined for $0\leq\theta\leq{\pi\over2}$.

As a next step one considers polar angles in the $(x,y)$-plane, measured counterclockwise from the positive $x$-axis, and one identifies these angles with the length of the corresponding arc on the unit circle $S^1$. When $0\leq\theta\leq{\pi\over2}$ then $\sin\theta$ is  the $y$-coordinate of the point where the second leg of the angle in question intersects $S^1$. It is then  *natural to define* $\sin \theta$ for all $\theta\in[0,2\pi]$ in this way, and a further step leads to the definition of $\sin\theta$ for all $\theta\in{\mathbb R}$: For arbitrary $\theta>0$ spool a thread of length $\theta$ counterclockwise around $S^1$ with initial point at $(1,0)$. The $y$-coordinate of the endpoint is then *defined* to be $\sin\theta$. It is then intuitively obvious that the function $\sin$ is periodic.

This sounds all very simple and natural. The difficulties begin when we try to make the above thought  process mathematically precise. In the first place we need a precise notion of angle: axiomatic euclidean geometry allows comparison and addition of angles, but does not provide an identification of angles with real numbers, which is inherent in the concept of the $\sin$ function.

Comment: Why is the notion of the angle not "precise" in the case of the Unit Circle? How is it lacking?

Comment: Try to define "angle" without ending up in a tautology. From your point of view, "angle"="point on unit circle" (or on a protractor) seems to be the closest. Then sin and cos are just the coordinates of that point. However, the complicated part is to associate points of the unit circle with real numbers. On a protractor, some points are marked, this however gives no general rule for the other points.

Comment: @Assad How can you assign a real number to an angle ?
Angle ,precisely, are defined by trigonometric functions :)

Comment: @FardadPouran you can assign a real number to an angle by using the radian measure.

Comment: @Assad, Is it possible to define radian measure without sine and cosine ?
I think radian can be defined by the ratio of arc length and circle perimeter, And arc length is just known by some integral whose integrand must be parameterized by sine and cosine function !

Comment: It's really an interesting problem, isn't it ? :)

Answer (score 3):

The proof is based simply on similar triangles. If a right-angled triangle has an angle $\theta$ then the other two angles are $90^{\circ}$ and $(90-\theta)^{\circ}$. If two triangles have the same angles then they are similar.

My picture shows two similar triangles: $\triangle OAB$ and $\triangle OA'B'$.

Since $\theta = \angle AOB$ then, by definition 
$$\sin\theta = \frac{\|AB\|}{\|OB\|}$$

Since $\theta = \angle A'OB'$ then, by definition
$$\sin\theta = \frac{\|A'B'\|}{\|OB'\|}$$

We can show that $\sin \theta$ has a single, unique value if we can show that the two ratios agree.

Let $T$ be the linear transformation given by an enlargement, centre $O$, with scale factor $\lambda$, such that $T(A) = A'$ and $T(B) = B'$. We have $\|A'B'\|=\lambda\|AB\|$ and $\|OB'\| = \lambda\|OB\|$, hence
$$\frac{\|A'B'\|}{\|OB'\|} = \frac{\lambda\|AB\|}{\lambda\|OB\|}=\frac{\|AB\|}{\|OB\|}$$

This shows that the ratio of the opposite side to the hypotenuse is the same for any two similar, right-angled triangles with angle $\theta$. That means that $\sin\theta$ is uniquely, well-defined.

(N.B. Similarity allows rotation and reflection as well as enlargement. However, rotations and reflections preserve lengths and so preserve ratios of lengths.)

[image]

Comment: Why does proving two triangles are similar mean that sin and cos are functions? More exposition would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: @Assad If two triangles have the same three angles then the are similar. In our case the angles are $\theta$, $90$ and $90-\theta$. I have shown that the ratio of the side opposite $\theta$ to the hypotenuse is the same for all similar triangles, i.e. $\sin\theta$ has a single, unique value.

Comment: This is the one.

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid that from a pre-calculus point of view, there is no consistent definition of the functional relationships that allows to discuss them as real functions (real valued in one real variable).

The big gap to be closed is the notion of an angle. In geometry, an angle is defined by a pair of rays from the same point. These most often occur at corners of triangles. All geometrically similar pairs of rays define the same angle. You can arrange such an equivalent pair of rays to have the first ray horizontal pointing to the right, then the second ray is uniquely characterized by a point on the unit circle (after fixing an origin and a unit length). The coordinates of that point then are the cosine and sine of that (equivalence class of) angle(s).

Then there are some angles that can be constructed and calculated geometrically by constructing regular n-gons and thus dividing the unit circle into n equal parts. n=3,4,6,8,12 are easy, n=5 is possible without too much effort. By bisection one can enclose any other angle in fractions of the full circle, starting from these known fractions, but this goes close to limit arguments, which already is calculus.

One can identify points on the unit circle with rotation matrices or complex numbers, which simplifies the angle arithmetic. Doubling an angle is then squaring the matrix or complex number, bisecting an angle corresponds to a square root. This gives functional equations that in their components are the trigonometric identities. Demanding continuity and differentiability at the zero angle will also give the trigonometric functions as unique solutions. However, this uniqueness is again enforced by calculus arguments.

Answer (score 0):

It follows from the definition of $\sin(\theta)$ as a ratio of length of $\theta$'s opposite side to hypotenuse ([Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sine)).

As long as hypotenuse length is not equal to zero (otherwise the triangle degenerates into line or point), the division is a function which yields only one associated value.

Comment: If the hypotenuse is zero, the triangle has degenerated into a point, not a line segment.

Comment: This is not really a proper definition of the real functions. For that you have to first define what the angle is and how you measure it, i.e., how the real argument $θ$ and the geometric object "anlge" relate to each other. It is ok for calculations with triangles and angles as classes of geometrically equivalent pairs of rays.

Answer (score 0):

More precisely, in Analysis, **sin(x)** is defined as the limit of a specific series.

Before, we know that the below series converges for every $x\in\mathbb{R}$:
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)!}x^{2n+1}$$
And then we define :
$$\sin(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)!}x^{2n+1}$$
By this definition, $\sin(x)$ has all properties of the elementary definition (ratio of sides in a right-angled triangle).

Comment: I've yet to come across this, I'm studying precalculus mathematics

Answer (score 0):

If you want to verify this intuitively for yourself, then this answer could prove to be helpful. But remember, *this is not a proof*.

First try to visualize what $\sin\theta$ looks like. If you need some help, this is what it looks like.

[image]

Now remember that if $\sin\theta$ is a function, then for a certain $\theta$, there can be only *one* value of $\sin\theta$.

Now pick a random point on the $x-$axis. This is going to be your value for $\theta$. Now a draw a line perpendicular to the $x-$axis through that point. Now *is it possible for that line to intersect the sine curve at more than one point?* Try it out for different values of $x$. No, it is completely impossible for that line to intersect that curve at more than one point.

This means that for a certain $\theta$, there is only one associated value of $\sin\theta$.

$\sin\theta$ and $\cos\theta$ are pretty much the same. Notice that $\cos\theta=\sin(\theta +\frac{\pi}{2})$. So if you move the sine curve by $\frac{\pi}{2}$ to the right, you're going to get the curve for $\cos\theta$. And $\sin\theta$ and $\cos\theta$ *look* exactly the same. So you can use the same argument.

Finally, I repeat that this is not a proof. But I hope this helps you see it intuitively.

The figure is taken from [here](http://jwilson.coe.uga.edu/emat6680/dunbar/Assignment1/sine_curves_KD.html).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, however I am already aware of this